# Stripe elements - issue with apple pay - payment window appear and disappear in a second

Tags: javascript, php, payment-gateway, stripe-payments

I connected Stipe payments to the site using js API v3 and stripe elements. Everything works (including google pay) expect apple pay. When a user clicks on apple pay button - payment window appears just for a brief second and then disappear. The site domain was verified according to [Stripe wiki for js v2, v3 doesn't have such page](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay/web/v2#going-live). Can't find any errors. Will be grateful for any hints or even direction. Thank you.

Code sample:

```
          paymentRequest = stripe.paymentRequest({
          country: 'GB',
          currency: 'gbp',
          total: {
              label: 'Upgrade',
              amount: 11400,
          },
          requestPayerName: false,
          requestPayerEmail: true,
      });

      var prButton = elements.create('paymentRequestButton', {
          paymentRequest: paymentRequest,
      });

      paymentRequest.canMakePayment().then(function (result) {
                  if (result) {
                      prButton.mount('#payment-request-button');
                  } else {
                      document.getElementById('payment-request-error').innerHTML = "Your browser doesn't support Google or Apple Wallet";
                      document.getElementById('payment-request-button').style.display = 'none';
                  }

                  paymentRequest.on('paymentmethod', function (ev) {
                      stripe.confirmCardPayment(
                          clientSecret, {
                              payment_method: ev.paymentMethod.id
                          }, {
                              handleActions: false
                          }
                      ).then(function (confirmResult) {
                          if (confirmResult.error) {
                              ev.complete('fail');
                          } else {
                              ev.complete('success');
                              if (confirmResult.paymentIntent.status === "requires_action") {
                                  stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret).then(function (result) {
                                      if (result.error) {
                                          alert("Error, try new payment method");
                                      } else {
                                          orderComplete(confirmResult.paymentInten.id);
                                      }
                                  });
                              } else {
                                  orderComplete(confirmResult.paymentInten.id);
                              }
                          }
                      });
                  });
                
                  /*
                  Some code
                  */
                 
                  // update request price if user select different price
                  paymentRequest.update({
                      total: {
                          label: 'Upgrade',
                          amount: finalPrice * 100,
                      },
                  })
```

Comment: Dev console shows error: POST https://api.stripe.com/v1/apple_pay/sessions 401

Comment: Did you ever find out what was causing this?

Comment: I am looking for a solution to this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Does Apple Pay work for you in the [example in the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button)? Do you have an example of your implementation available online somewhere to access, or can you reproduce this in a JSFiddle or CodeSandbox?

Two suggestions to try:

1. In your calls to `orderComplete` you appear to have a typo on `paymentInten**t**.id` -- missing the `t` at the end in both instances.
2. I wonder if your `paymentRequest.update` is causing issues. I'm not familiar with the behaviour of this part of the API so I'd recommend disabling to simplify diagnostics.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will provide jsfidle a little bit later. Btw the only error that dev console shows - POST https://api.stripe.com/v1/apple_pay/sessions 401.